# SSIS Data Conversion issue

Tags: sql-server, excel, datetime, ms-access, ssis

I have an Access file which for specific reasons imports data from an excel file where 2 of columns are 'text' but the data is actually time in format mm:ss

The SQL table this needs importing into has the 2 columns defined as datetime which again is required.

I am trying to use SSIS to import and convert the two columns into a format that the SQL table will accept, but I have tried several datatypes from file_timestamp to date but always fails.

Note I am also new to this, can anyone help with this conversion.

Background:
The Access file was originally set to datetime but I have recently found out that the access file import process sometimes imports the data wrong i.e. data should be 00:21:21 but will be imported as 21:21:00 this does not happen on every import and the excel file and columns formats are identical if import as text to access then data is correct, so I am trying to resolve the issue in the transfer from Access to SQL in the automated JOB

Thanks

Comment: We really need a sample of what you see in Excel, and what you expect in SQL Server to help you with this question. See [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some help on what we need to help you.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: Odds are you will not get any direct canned data conversion to work.  You are going to have to manipulate the string into an arrangement that a SQL data type likes to convert from.  Lookup SQL string to datetime, and you will find lots of help